Share Application Database for Power BI or similar
We built a web application with an SQL Server database and want to provide users with tools for analyzing the data in Power BI (or similar tools)
Is sharing DB URL recommendable from a security standpoint?
Users would only have access to specific views, so data could not be modified.
